# Passar dados pelo link - aplicação php

Tags: php, sql-select, link

Gente eu não estou conseguindo fazer algo, sou iniciante em php e progamação web e estou tentando fazer uma página para receber o ID de um usuário qualquer através de um click no link:

```
  `while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {

                            $id_usuario = $linha['ID_usuario'];
                            $name = $linha['nome'];
                            $Sexo= $linha['sexo']; 

                            echo "<tr> <td><a href='#'>$id_usuario</a></td> <td>$name</td> <td>$Sexo</td> <td>Tipo</td> </tr>"; //falta definir a pagina


                                    }`
```

É um procedimento simples eu acredito, na outra página eu gostaria que pegasse o id do usuário e fizesse um *Select* em todas as informações desse usuário cadastrado no banco, mas quero saber como eu poderia fazer isso nessa outra página

Comment: Colega, primeiro: NUNCA USE GET PARA PASSAR USUARIO E SENHA. Segundo,dê uma pesquisada aqui no Stack mesmo, existem CENTENAS de exemplos de login usando PDO, que atualmente é o mais seguro. Veja aqui um ótimo exemplo: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/como-criar-um-sistema-de-login-com-niveis-de-permissao

Comment: Obrigado Diego, já dei uma estudada nisso

Comment: @Diego PDO não é mais seguro que mysqli. Usando certo, mysqli é até mais seguro, pois o PDO por padrão simula os _prepared statements_, diferente do mysqli que faz nativo. A única "vantagem" que o PDO tem que facilita pra trocar o DB, coisa que normalmente só faz sentido em bibliotecas maiores (e mesmo assim, se a biblioteca for bem otimizada, vai dar preferência para engines nativos).

Comment: @Bacco, my bad. Dei uma opinião pessoal sobre a segurança, sem embasamento técnico. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @Diego Lembrando que ambos se prestam bem ao serviço, só não quis deixar o coitado do mysqli levando fama ruim à toa kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você deve passar o id pelo link:

```
 echo "<tr> <td><a href='dados.php?id=".$id_usuario."'>$id_usuario</a></td> <td>$name</td> <td>$Sexo</td> <td>Tipo</td> </tr>";
```

Na outra página você precisa fazer uma consulta ao banco de dados pegando o `id`:

```
<?php
// retirado de codigosnaweb.com - scripts grátis para o seu site

// PODE SER SEPARADO O TRECHO ABAIXO PARA SER CHAMADO POR INCLUDE
define("SERVIDOR", "<endereço do servidor de banco de dados>");
define("USUARIO", ",<usuário>");
define("SENHA", "<senha>");
define("BANCODEDADOS", ",<nome do banco de dados>");
$conecta = new mysqli(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA, BANCODEDADOS); // CONECTA

if ($conecta->connect_error) {
    trigger_error("ERRO NA CONEXÃO: "  . $conecta->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
// PODE SER SEPARADO O TRECHO ACIMA PARA SER CHAMADO POR INCLUDE

$sql = "$sql = "SELECT * FROM suatabela WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."";"; // CONSULTA
$query = $conecta->query($sql); // RODA A CONSULTA
$linhas = $query->num_rows;
if($linhas >= 1) { // SE HÁ LINHAS
    while($colunas = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " {$colunas["texto"]} "; // DADOS DA CONSULTA
    }
    $query->free(); // LIBERANDO OS DADOS DA CONSULTA
} else {
    echo "Não há resultados"; // SEM RESULTADOS
}
$conecta->close(); // FECHANDO A CONEXÃO
?>
```

Substitua as informações do seu banco (nome, endereço, usuário e senha) nesse código e salve num arquivo "dados.php".