# como carregar dados de uma pagina de acordo com o ID clicado?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

O que eu quero é bem simples, quero que ao clicar no nome da pessoa, carregue uma outra pagina com os dados completos da pessoa de acordo com os dados clicados anteriormente e ali eu possa editar os dados dessa pessoa e salvar no dessa pessoa no Banco de Dados MYSQL.

Comment: o que você já fez?

Comment: so o login ate agora, e a pagina que vai receber os dados

Comment: Mas a sua dúvida é como passar esse id, ou como consultar. Coloque código se possivel, para exemplificar melhor

Comment: Como colocar ele no Href para ir para outra pagina e nesta pagina carregar os dados do id que cliquei antes e ali começar a trabalhar com o cadastro dessa pessoa

Comment: @williamDePaula é daquela forma que voce quer? Como respondi ali?

Comment: É assim mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: @WilliamDePaula marque como resposta então :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar dados pelo link - aplicação php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117858/passar-dados-pelo-link-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php)

Answer (score 2):

Um método simples e sem tratamento, é você utilizar o metodo `$_GET`. Voce pode passar pelo link da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="pagina.php?id=5"><a/>
```

Esse `5`no caso, é o seu id, que você vai recuperar na outra pagina da seguinte forma. Na `pagina.php` , você faria:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Espero ter ajudado!